# django huey is always returning empty queryset while filtering

Tags: python, django, redis, python-huey

```
@db_task()
def test_db_access(tenant_id, batch_obj):
    print('DBAccess')
    print(tenant_id)
    print(batch_obj.id)
    files = File.objects.filter(batch_id=batch_obj.id)
    print(files)
```

If I run this in django without django-huey, I get a filtered queryset but if I start using django-huey, I'm always getting an empty queryset. Only 'DBAccess' is getting printed and files is always '[]'.

Do I have to add other settings in settings.py?
This is my current huey settings

```
# Huey - Task Queue
HUEY = {
    'name': 'appname',
    'consumer': {
        'workers': 4, 
        'worker_type': 'thread'
    },
    'immediate': False,
    'connection': {
        'host': RedisConfig.HOST,
        'port': RedisConfig.PORT,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass an object as an argument to that function and it's probably not getting serialized - huey uses `pickle` to serialize function call data that is passed to the consumer. Instead, change your function to accept a `batch_obj` identifier like this:

```py
@db_task()
def test_db_access(tenant_id, batch_obj_id):
    print('DBAccess')
    print(tenant_id)
    print(batch_obj_id)
    files = File.objects.filter(batch_id=batch_obj_id)
    print(files)
```

and pass in `batch_obj_id=batch_obj.id` when you're calling `test_db_access`. Alternatively, you can write a [custom serializer](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#serializer), but it should be much simpler to just pass the numerical identifier.